# My paper got accepted; acquaintance's paper wasn't. Should I thank them?

Tags: publications, peer-review

A week before submitting to a peer reviewed publication, me and an acquaintance exchanged drafts for comments. My acquaintance described my work as preliminary, listing many ways in which the work could improve. The tone was slightly harsh, but the comments were constructive. They seemed to be relatively confident about their paper.

My paper was accepted, but I heard that their paper was not. Should I thank my acquaintance? On the one hand it is courteous to do so, since they read a draft and helped me to improve. On the other hand, it could come across as schadenfreude if they are a bit on the sensitive side.

Comment: Are you talking about thanking them privately, or in the acknowledgements of the paper?  The former you should have already done when they gave you the comments in the first place, and the latter seems entirely appropriate in any case.

Comment: I already thanked them when they gave their comments. I will also thank them in the acknowledgement. The question is whether I should send an email of thanks now.

Comment: I see.  Given that you've already thanked them, I don't see the need to do it again.

Comment: I agree that you should acknowledge this person's help in the paper. That has nothing to do with the fate of his/her paper.  But, having already thanked this person privately, I see no reason for sending another thank-you e-mail with the news that your paper was accepted. That might indeed look like Schadenfreude.

Comment: Acknowledgement is meant for exactly such occasions. Why are you hesitating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My paper was accepted, but I heard that their paper was not. Should I thank my acquaintance? On the one hand it is courteous to do so, since they read a draft and helped me to improve. On the other hand, it could come across as schadenfreude if they are a bit on the sensitive side.

Yes, please thank them. That your paper got accepted and theirs was not may or may not sting a bit, but that will be true independently of whether you thank them or not.

That being said, the protocol in such cases seems to be that they will approach you and congratulate you on your accepted paper, and this is a great time to heartfully thank them for their help and express that you are sorry about their paper being rejected.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: a polite, discrete form of honesty is invariably the best first approximation for a prescription of behavior. Especially, thanking those who've genuinely and specifically helped you is (at least to several orders of approximation) a good thing. The "glory" of having a paper accepted is not truly so great, although it may seem otherwise at the beginning. After some point, receiving thanks for helping can be more professionally gratifying than the traditional notion of publishing per se, since *publications* do not necessarily help anyone other than the author.

Even though some things are unavoidably competitive, in many cases that aspect is not truly the central feature of the thing. My advice is to try to separate "the game" from "the science" (etc.), as difficult as that may be when one is in the throes of the thing. But, in any case, thinking too much about "the game" seriously corrupts one's clarity.